# Corona SDK - Make a character pass through a platform

Tags: coronasdk

I'm building a game that has a character which should jump up on multiple platforms.
The jumping functionality is done, but I would like if the character is just below a platform (static body), when I press the "jump" button, the character should pass through that platform and then sit on it.
Right now it collides with the platform, and character cannot jump on it.

Do you have any idea how this can be achieved?

Right now the platforms are represented by rectangles with "static" body type:

```
local platform = display.newRect(  50, 280, 150, 10 )
platform:setFillColor ( 55, 55, 55)
physics.addBody ( platform, "static", {density=1.0, friction=1.0, bounce=0 })
```

And I was thinking if I could change, or remove the body type of platform when the character collids with it, so he can pass trough platform, but I don't know how to do this, or in general if this will work... maybe there are some built in techniques on how to achieve the effect I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the platform into a sensor (Box2D term for object with collision box, that trigger a event but does not trigger a "physical" collision.

Then detect the direction of the collision, and then handle it :)

There are lots of tutorials on that... I cannot find them now, I might edit this later with the links to them.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to achieve this with onPrecolition, onPostCollision listeners.

Comment: If you found it this is good! The tutorials explain exactly how to use those listeners.